# How to prevent React Native to dismiss keyboard

Tags: react-native

In a react-native form, when switching from one TextInput to the next one, the second grabs focus for an instant and then suddenly RN dismisses the keyboard.

I have `onSubmitEditing` coded to move to next input, but the user needs to click on enter in the keyboard, I can also override `onEndEditing` however that forces you to move to the next input and maybe you didn't touch that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the problem is related to having TextInputs within a ScrollView, focus between inputs in this component doesn't work as expected.

Comment: `<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true} ... />`

Comment: Thanks so much for this hint

Answer (score 1):

`keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` is deprecated so need to use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"`